# C# - Dynamic pattern matching cases in switch expression?

Tags: c#, pattern-matching

I've recently been finding a ton of value in simplifying branching logic into switch expressions and utilizing pattern matching.  Particulary in the case where I have multiple data elements that need to be considered.

```
return tuple switch
{
   ("Foo", "Bar") => "FooBar",
   ("Foo", _ ) => "Foo",
   (_, "Bar") => "Bar",
   (_, _) => "Default Value"
};
```

My expected behaviour for any given value of "tuple" variable would yield as follows:

```
var tuple = ("Hello", "World") -> "Default Value"
var tuple = ("Foo", "World") -> "Foo"
var tuple = ("Foo", "") -> "Foo"
var tuple = ("Foo", null) -> "Foo"
var tuple = ("Hello", "Bar") -> "Bar"
```

This all works well and good.

I've recently identified a situation, where what I want is a sequence of rules that have to be checked in a "most specific to least specific" order, with reasonable defaults if a value does not exist.  So effectively the same as the pattern matching sequence above.   However, I need my end users to have the capability of configuring the patterns themselves, and the pattern cases to be dynamic (i.e coming from a database table).

So, given these data records:

```
Input1, Input2, ReturnValue
"Foo",  "Bar",  "FooBar"
"Foo",  NULL,   "Foo"
NULL,   "Bar",  "Bar"
NULL,   NULL,   "Default Value"
```

I'd want to "generate" these cases, exactly like my hardcoded example above.

```
   ("Foo", "Bar") => "FooBar",
   ("Foo", _ ) => "Foo",
   (_, "Bar") => "Bar",
   (_, _) => "Default Value"
```

Then if a user wanted to add a new "rule", they'd add a new record

```
Input1, Input2,  ReturnValue
"Hello","World", "I'm the super special return value".
```

which would create the following pattern case:

```
("Hello", "World") => "I'm the super special return value",
```

and the corresponding results when evaluating would be:

```
var tuple = ("Hello", "World") -> "I'm the super special return value"
var tuple = ("Hello", "Other") -> "Default Value"
```

In my mind, I would want to do something to the effect of:

```
var switchOptions = dataRecords.Select(record =>
{
   var pattern = (record.Input1 ?? '_', record.Input2 ?? '_');
   var func = (pattern) => record.Result;
   return func;
});
//and then somehow build the switch expression out of these options.
```

It makes sense why this doesn't work for a few reasons, I'm sure not limited to:

1. the switch expression syntax isn't an object that has AddPattern().
2. The char '_' and the _ operator in the expression aren't the same thing...

The other option I thought of is to map the record set into a dictionary, where the Key would be the Tuple (columns: Input1, Input2), and the value is the expected return value (column: ReturnValue).   The problem with this is, it doesn't provide me any capacity to treat NULL database value as a discard pattern, by a simple key lookup.

**At the end of the day, my question is this:** I assume the switch expression syntax is just some nice sugar overtop of a more complicated implementation under the hood. Is the idea of a "dynamically" switch expression something I can accomplish with an already existing implementation within C# 9?  Or am I barking up the wrong tree, and need to fully implement this on my own?

Comment: The `switch` keyword isn't sugar, exactly, it goes back to C, in fact. You can't add anything to `switch` because it is a keyword, not an object. In your case, though, why not just combine the two strings and use regex? Maybe your real life use case requires more complicated types, though.

Comment: You can build your own interpreter for pattern matching or use a `switch` statement in an `Expression` tree. Unfortunately the C# / .Net teams haven't been updating `Expression` for a long time and it is woefully out of date, so `switch` expressions are not supported.

Comment: Checking more closely, `Expression` also doesn't have any pattern matching implementation, or `ValueTuple`, so it isn't possible. You have to roll your own pattern matching interpretor. Or embed the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're looking for some kind of code-generation, but with a bit of Linq aggregation you can put your patterns/records in a sequence and use the result as a function that kinda acts like the switch-expression pattern matching. It's important that `dataRecords` contains the records in the order you want them to be evaluated:

```
public record Record(string Input1, string Input2, string ReturnValue);
public record Pattern(Func<string, string, bool> Predicate, string ReturnValue);

Pattern CreatePattern(Record rec)
{
    return new (
        (l, r) =>
            (l == rec.Input1 || rec.Input1 == null)
            && (r == rec.Input2 || rec.Input2 == null),
        rec.ReturnValue
    );
}

// Create your pattern matching "switch-expression"
var switchExp = dataRecords
    .Reverse()
    .Select(CreatePattern)
    .Aggregate<Pattern, Func<string, string, string>>(
        (_, _) => null,
        (next, pattern) =>
            (l, r) => pattern.Predicate(l, r) ? pattern.ReturnValue : next(l, r)
    );

switchExp("abc", "bar"); // "bar"
```

See it [in action](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LwleMC).

Comment: Excellent.  This is right in line with what I was looking for and trying to figure out.  I never thought to use a fold function like that to traverse through my sequence of patterns.  Thank you very much.   I'm going to play with this a little more to truly grasp it and try and apply this approach in my domain with more than just strings.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to implement this on your own. The switch pattern matching is similar to the switch case in regular use, requiring compile time constants, and is likely implemented with a jump table. Therefore it cannot be modified in runtime.

What you are trying to achieve feels like shouldn't be too hard. Something like this

```cs
PatternDict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
PatternDict["_"] = new Dictionary<string, string>();
PatternDict["_"]["_"] = null;
```

With the update code be:

```cs
Dictionary<string, string> dict;
if (!PatternDict.TryGetValue(input1, out dict)) {
  dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  dict["_"] = "default";
}
dict[input2] = returnValue;
PatternDict[input1] = dict;
```

And retrieval code be:

```cs
Dictionary<string, string> dict;
if (!PatternDict.TryGetValue(input1, out dict)) {
  dict = PatternDict["_"];
}
string returnVal;
if (!dict.TryGetValue(input2, out returnVal)) {
  returnVal = dict["_"];
}
return returnVal;
```

You might also be able to change `string` to nullable strings `string?` if you are using new version of C# that supports it to use `null` as your default value key.